# Alternate source for a package removed from a testing or unstable repo

Tags: debian, package-management, drivers, php, testing

https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/php-mongo

php-mongo 1.6.10-1 has been removed from unstable and testing and I was using it in a VM to maintain some legacy code. When I came to provision another VM recently I noticed that it had been removed in favor for an older version.

I need this version because it fixes issues with authentication as discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29792674/cant-authenticate-on-mongodb-with-php.

Is there any other way of sourcing this package from an alternate repository?

Comment: All released debian packages are reachable on http://snapshot.debian.org/

Comment: @IporSircer looks promising, I will take a look, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can find it on [snapshots](http://snapshot.debian.org/package/php-mongo/1.6.10-1/). To add the corresponding repository, use the following `sources.list` entry (or as a new file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`):

```
deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20150723T034653Z/ unstable main
```